# Is there a terminal emulator which can notify when there is an output with certain pattern?

Tags: terminal, konsole

Konsole, for example, only provides option to notify when there is activity or silence.

My particular case: I run a long-running program which turns out to occasionally prompt for user/password. It would be nice to be notified when a prompt string like /Please enter username/ appears on the terminal output, instead of having to repeatedly visit the terminal emulator window manually.

Comment: Running the program under shell mode in Emacs is an option, although I don't use the shell from within Emacs on a regular basis.

Answer (score 0):

Pipe it like this:

```bsh
yourprogram | while read xx ;do wall -- "$xx" ;done
```